# The order of priority_queue when overloading the operator?

Tags: c++

Hi I am trying to understand how the comparator works for priority_queue in c++. It confuses me for a long time.

Let's say we have this struct:

```
struct compare{
  public:
  bool operator()(Node& a,Node& b) // overloading both operators 
  {
      return a.w < b.w: // if you want increasing order;(i.e increasing for minPQ)
      return a.w > b.w // if you want reverse of default order;(i.e decreasing for minPQ)
   }
};
```

And we can create the pq in this way:

```
priority_queue<Node,vector<Node>,compare> pq;
```

I want to know why "operator<" is minq, i.e. `pq.top()` is the minimum? while "operator>" is maxq?

Answer (score 0):

If the ordering function returns true, then the first object will come before the second object.

So if you have

```
return a.w < b.w;
```

and it's true then `a` will come before `b`.

Same with

```
return a.w > b.w;
```

If it's true then `a` will come before `b`.

This is well [documented](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue).